# A conversion that C-style cast can handle, but C++ casts cannot

Tags: c++, c, casting

[It is said](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/explicit_cast) that C-style cast just tries to apply different combination of C++ casts and the first allowed combination is used. However, I have a feeling that I heard that there are situations that only C-style cast can handle, while none of combination of C++ casts are allowed.

Am I wrong? Is that true that *any* C-style cast in *any* context (in C++) can be replaced with a proper combination of C++ casts?

**UPD** Thanks to [Cheers and hth. - Alf](https://stackoverflow.com/users/464581/cheers-and-hth-alf), we have an example that C++ casts cannot handle in the meaning they cannot produce *defined* and *expected* behavior. Advanced question is to provide an example which C++ casts cannot handle meaning it cannot be even *compiled*?

Comment: "I have a feeling that I heard that there are situations that only C-style cast can handle, while none of combination of C++ casts are allowed" -- I suspect that what you heard is rather that C permits some casts that C++ does not.  This has nothing to do with the *meaning* of a C-style cast in terms of C++ casts.  I haven't an example handy, however.

Comment: @JohnBollinger, you can still perform the same cast through a combination of C++ style casts.

Comment: Of course not, that would make C++-style casts inferior.

Comment: @zenith, not neccessarily inferior, just more strictly typed :)

Comment: <resists the impulse to start a language war>

Comment: @JohnBollinger, there is nothing to war about here. At least, I see no points.

Comment: Isn't there always `reinterpret_cast`?

Comment: @CompuChip no, `reinterpret_cast` cannot even do some things `static_cast` can, while both are orthogonal to `const_cast`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Cast to inaccessible base can only be expressed as a C style cast (one of the syntactic variants). In that context it is equivalent to a `static_cast`, which may change the address, except that `static_cast` can't access the base.

Example:

```
struct Base
{
    int x = 42;
};

struct Oh_my
    : private Base
{
    virtual ~Oh_my() {}
};

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
auto main() -> int
{
    Oh_my o;
    cout << "C cast: " << ((Base&)o).x << endl;
    cout << "reinterpret_cast: " << reinterpret_cast<Base&>(o).x << endl;
}
```

Output with MingW g++ in Windows 7:

```
C cast: 42
reinterpret_cast: 4935184
```

But since it's pretty Undefined Behavior, the last output operation could just crash.

Comment: A sample would help. My first thought was that `reinterpret_cast` can do anything, but I eventually thought of a case where `reinterpret_cast` might require pointer arithmetic and knowledge of compiler internals to work.  Was that what you were thinking, or do you have an even better example?

Comment: I'll have to write one and get another cup of coffee. But, OK. :)

Comment: @MooingDuck `struct A { int i; }; struct B { int i; }; struct C : private A, private B { };`, then doing a C-style cast from `C *` to either `A *` or `B *` will work, whereas a `static_cast` will fail, and a `reinterpret_cast` will give the wrong result for at least one of them.

Comment: @hvd: right, that's the case I thought of. `reinterpret_cast` can work, but it requires pointer arithmetic and knowledge of compiler internals, so I would count that as "C++ casts can't handle".

Comment: What is the purpose of the virtual destructor? If I remove that, I get the same output with both casts.

Comment: It's the same as with @hvd's multiple inheritance, to *practically* ensure that the (or at least one) base sub-object is not at the same address as the most derived object.

Comment: Brilliant. Let's go to the level two. An example that C++ casts cannot even _compile_? :)

Comment: @Mikhail: Pretty sure `reinterpret_cast` will _compile_ for anything C will cast, assuming the types are the same for each.